# jQuery UI Accordion Disobeys Height

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

This should be any easy one for you.  I have an accordion that I'd like to be a fixed height.  Each pane should be the same size, if there is any overflow on a pane a scroll bar should appear.  In the code below the scroll bars appear on load for the first pane, but after the first pane change, the accordion expands it's height, so scroll bars are no longer needed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
   <head>

      <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){     
        $('#accordion').accordion({autoHeight: false, clearStyle: true});
     });
      </script>

   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="accordion">
     <h3><a href="#">First Section</a></h3>
     <div style="height:50px; overflow:auto">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut venenatis vehicula dui, quis volutpat odio bibendum a. Proin posuere convallis lorem id mattis. Vestibulum lacinia lacinia enim ut euismod. Aenean sit amet tincidunt nunc. Vestibulum gravida, ipsum in tempor dictum, diam nulla auctor purus, a vehicula ante odio quis massa. Pellentesque imperdiet urna ut elit adipiscing ac gravida lectus facilisis. Curabitur laoreet, justo vel dapibus auctor, enim sem dapibus nulla, sed lacinia felis felis sit amet dolor. Nulla lacus dolor, tincidunt convallis sodales vitae, interdum a sapien. Cras ut iaculis orci. Mauris vel nisl vel leo venenatis hendrerit. Duis aliquet lobortis purus, non malesuada lorem sagittis quis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc sit amet posuere eros. Nam vel turpis at sem adipiscing scelerisque a ac dolor. Morbi lobortis tristique felis, at aliquam libero suscipit sed. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec porta lorem sed nisl fermentum pulvinar vehicula risus tempus. Integer ultricies dignissim vehicula. Morbi non dolor a arcu rutrum congue. Fusce non urna vitae eros blandit vehicula quis vel ligula. 
     </div>

     <h3><a href="#">Second Section</a></h3>
     <div style="height:50px; overflow:auto">
        Etiam varius, orci sit amet pharetra laoreet, diam augue dictum justo, et aliquam enim leo ut nulla. Quisque mi nunc, sagittis at euismod vel, feugiat a erat. In a metus quam. Pellentesque ullamcorper volutpat congue. Nunc facilisis varius velit eu lacinia. Quisque est nulla, tempus commodo gravida quis, consequat ut felis. Donec mattis, neque sagittis feugiat sollicitudin, augue lectus vulputate ligula, eget interdum nulla massa at nunc. Proin rhoncus nunc non felis mattis accumsan. Aliquam metus ligula, adipiscing ac ullamcorper vel, lobortis non erat. Aenean placerat libero porta enim dictum malesuada molestie sapien ultricies. Nullam ac commodo ligula.  
     </div>

     <h3><a href="#">Third Section</a></h3>
     <div style="height:50px; overflow:auto">
Morbi nec risus velit, eget ornare nibh. Duis semper elementum erat, ac egestas purus congue et. Sed commodo lacinia lorem, ac semper risus dapibus mattis. Aliquam quam quam, ultrices quis luctus sit amet, cursus vitae dolor. Nam id lectus justo. Pellentesque in leo sit amet metus eleifend lobortis eget nec turpis. Praesent vitae magna eget mauris cursus tempus vel at mi. Nulla vitae leo accumsan magna mollis luctus. Curabitur viverra nisi ac nisl pulvinar gravida. Curabitur consectetur, diam non placerat sagittis, velit nunc porttitor quam, vel interdum lorem est ut arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque vitae leo nunc.

     </div>
   </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appears that the `height` property is being animated as the accordion opens and closes.  So once the top panel has been closed one time, it's height has been changed from the one specified in the inline style and is 'lost'.

I found when I factor the style out into the header the accordion works as desired:

```
   <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #accordion>div{
            height:50px;
            overflow:auto;
        }
    </style>
   </head>
```

Comment: I added this style to my sample in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028470/how-to-show-more-than-one-item-in-jquery-ui-accordion-panel but it does not increase accordion panel height, it is still too small