# How to show more than one item in single jquery ui accordion opened section

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

jquery ui accordion contains lot of panels and every panel contains lot of single line menu items.
jqueryui accordion shows only single item in every panel. How to force accordion to show more items ?

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        fillSpace: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
    collapsible: true
});




<h3>
    <a href="#">mmmmmmm</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a target='DoklstlG' href='xxxxxx'>
                jjjjjj</a></li>
            <li><a target='DoklstlO' href='yyyyy'>Ostuarve</a></li>
            <li><a target='UnpaidG' href='zzzzzzz'>hjkhkjjsumine</a></li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
...
        </ul>
    </div>

<h3>
    <a href="#">kkkkk</a></h3>
<ul>
    <li><a target='DoklstlVL' href='nnnnnnnn'>V&#228;ljastus</a></li>
    <li><a target='DoklstlSL' href='mmmmmmmmmm'>Sissetulek</a></li>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation specifically instructs user to NOT do this:

> NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an accordion.

Source: [jQuery UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

*UPDATE*

Try changing `fillSpace: false` and `autoHeight : true`, see what that does.

Comment: There is only **single** section to be opened. Issue is that every single section showns only single item. Question asks how tro show more than one item in single section. There are no multiple sections open.

Answer (score 4):

as the other answer said, The documentation specifically instructs user to NOT do this

```
"NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an accordion."
```

yet, there is a way. i use it like this, and i find it very simple and useful:
create multiple one-item accordion panels one after another with collapsible set to true to emulate a multi-panel accordion.

here is the markup:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Third header</a></h3>
    <div>Third content</div>
</div>
```

here is the script:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({collapsible: true});
```

Comment: @marxus: thank you, great hack, I upvoted it. However I asked about showing multiple items in single panel. To save screen space it is ok to have only single item open at time in this case.